# Creating a filter bar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript and only have very basic knowledge of it at this stage. 
I am trying to create a filter bar that, when clicked, would set the opacity of the non-matched items to 0.2 and the matched item would remain at full opacity.

I have uploaded the html/css to show an example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rebeccasmith1301/zw2aozff/

```
<div id="filter-bar">
   <button onclick="findShoes()">Shoes</button>
   <button onclick="findTops()">Tops</button>
   <button onclick="findSkirts()">Skirts</button>
</div>
<div class="product-item">
   <p>Shoes</p>
</div>
<div class="product-item">
    <p>Tops</p>
</div>
```

Skirts

I have been experimenting with javascript written on a previous post that I found very helpful but due to my basic knowledge I have been unable to solve how to achieve the results I am aiming for.

I basically would like the user to be able to click on the button shoes (for example) and all of the divs that contain the word shoes to remain with full opacity and all other divs to have the class un-selected which lowers the opacity to 0.2. The divs that contain the products can be a class only, not an id as well.

Would anyone be able to help? This would be using mainly vanilla javascript.

Many thanks,

Becky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle with multiple words:** https://jsfiddle.net/qucwvqfr/1/

**Fiddle with white space removal**: https://jsfiddle.net/d15v3x0w/1/

Don't make a function for each possible variation of content, just make one function and give that a parameter. This javascript would check the `textContent` of the items, strip the whitespace from them, and change classes accordingly. The `hasClass`, `addClass`, and `removeClass` are helpers, focus on the `highlightItems` function.

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
  return !!ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
  if (!hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
  }
}

var highlightItems = function(itemName) {
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName("product-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        itemText = p[i].textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); // you don't need the .replace() part if you don't add extra white space in the HTML
        if ( !(itemText == itemName) ) {
            addClass(p[i], "un-selected");
        } else {
            removeClass(p[i], "un-selected");
        }
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
<div id="filter-bar">
    <button onclick="highlightItems('Shoes')">Shoes</button>
    <button onclick="highlightItems('Tops')">Tops</button>
    <button onclick="highlightItems('Skirts')">Skirts</button>
</div>
```

**Note:**

If you want to have multiple words inside the box, don't add any unnecessary white space inside the `div` tags. (You probably shouldn't do it anyway.) So the HTML usage would be like this:

```
<div class="product-item">Shoes and socks</div>
<div class="product-item">Tops</div>
<div class="product-item">Skirts</div>
```

Credits for the class-changing functions go to http://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Comment: Hello, thank you! That was very helpful.

At this stage I am prototyping but if I use your code how would you like me to credit you?

Thanks again

Comment: One other question, if there was several words in the div, for example 'Red leather shoes' how could the above code be extended to find the word 'shoes' within that sentence in the div?

Comment: @rebeccasmith_me No need to credit me. Check the last link to check if you need to credit the other guy. Anyway, I have added another fiddle and a note in the answer regarding multiword usage. TLDR: Don't add the unnecessary white space inside the `div` tags in the HTML, and you can match `textContent` as such.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a reliable way to select the specified items. I propose that you add a class `shoes`, `tops` and `skirts` to their respective elements:

```
<div class="product-item shoes">
    Shoes
</div>
<div class="product-item tops">
    Tops
</div>
<div class="product-item skirts">
    Skirts
</div>
```

Now, to select all elements that got `shoes` it's really easy:

```
var shoes = document.getElementsByClassName('shoes');
```

Selecting elements that don't have a class `shoes` is another story. Let say we start by collecting out all `product-item` elements, like so:

```
var products = document.getElementsByClassName('product-item');
```

From here on, you need to iterate all the elements inside the returned `nodeList` and check if they got a `shoes` class. A helper function that can help you with that:

```
function not(nodeList, cls){
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + cls + '\\b');
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(nodeList, function(acc, el){
        console.log(el, el.className.search(reg))
        if(el.className.match(reg) === null){
           acc.push(el);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []); 
}
```

So now, to get `products` that aren't `shoes`:

```
var notShoes = not(products, 'shoes');
```

To change the opacity of all the elements inside a nodeList we could use another helper function:

```
function changeOpacity(nodeList, opacity){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function(el){
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
    });
}
```

And to use it:

```
changeOpacity(shoes, 1.0);
changeOpacity(notShoes, 0.2);
```

All together in this snippet:

```js
function find(cls) {
    var clsList = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    var products = document.getElementsByClassName('product-item');
    var notCls = not(products, cls);
    changeOpacity(clsList, 1.0);
    changeOpacity(notCls, 0.2);
}

function not(nodeList, cls){
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + cls + '\\b');
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(nodeList, function(acc, el){
        console.log(el, el.className.search(reg))
        if(el.className.match(reg) === null){
           acc.push(el);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []); 
}

function changeOpacity(nodeList, opacity){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function(el){
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
    });
}
```

```css
/* Styling for filter bar*/
#filter-bar{
    width: 100%
}
    #filter-bar button{
        width: 30%
        float: left;
        margin: 0.5%;
    }
/* Styling for products*/
.product-item{
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Different options for products with button click*/
.un-selected{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-bar">
 <button onclick="find('shoes')">Shoes</button>
 <button onclick="find('tops')">Tops</button>
 <button onclick="find('skirts')">Skirts</button>
</div>


<div class="product-item shoes">
 Shoes
</div>
<div class="product-item tops">
 Tops
</div>
<div class="product-item skirts">
 Skirts
</div>
<div class="product-item skirts">
 Skirts
</div>
<div class="product-item shoes">
 Shoes
</div>
<div class="product-item tops">
 Tops
</div>
<div class="product-item skirts">
 Skirts
</div>
<div class="product-item skirts">
 Skirts
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with **jquery**:

**HTML**

```
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="a">Tops</button>
<button class="btn" id="b">Skirts</button>
<button class="btn" id="c">Shoes</button>

<!-- An element with an id is needed for the jQuery -->
<div id="parent">
  <!-- The base class is the box. Categories are then given as accessory classes. Any div can be in more than one category -->
  <div class="box product-item a b">Shoes &amp; Tops</div>
  <div class="box product-item a">Tops</div>
  <div class="box product-item b">Skirts</div>
  <div class="box product-item c">Shoes</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Styling for filter bar*/
#filter-bar{
    width: 100%
}
#filter-bar button{
    width: 30%
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
}
/* Styling for products*/
.product-item{
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Different options for products with button click*/
.un-selected{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyh2ggeu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filter(me) {

  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("product-item");
  console.log(me.textContent);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    
    var item = items[i];
    item.style.display = "";
  
    if (item.textContent.trim() !== me.textContent.trim() && me.textContent.trim() !== "All") {
      item.style.display = "none";
    }
  
  }
}
```

```css
/* Styling for filter bar*/
#filter-bar{
    width: 100%
}
    #filter-bar button{
        width: 30%
        float: left;
        margin: 0.5%;
    }
/* Styling for products*/
.product-item{
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Different options for products with button click*/
.un-selected{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-bar">
 <button onclick="filter(this)">Shoes</button>
 <button onclick="filter(this)">Tops</button>
 <button onclick="filter(this)">Skirts</button>
    <button onclick="filter(this)">All</button>
</div>


<div class="product-item">
 Shoes
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Tops
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Skirts
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Skirts
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Shoes
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Tops
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Skirts
</div>
<div class="product-item">
 Skirts
</div>
```